# Changing type of variable during dynamic array passing to a function

Tags: c, pointers

Guys my question is very simple but I am confused about the theory behind it. It would be lovely if someone can clarify.

I want to pass a dynamic array of a certain type of variable and have a function convert that type of variable to another one and do more work on it before returning it in the form of a variable array of that new variable.

Here's my not so functional code to show you what I was doing

```
#include <stdio.h>

//takes in unsigned char array, and returns unsigned short array

unsigned short foo( unsigned char *array, int size) 
{
    int i;
    unsigned short *LeArray = NULL;
    LeArray = (unsigned short*) malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned short));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) &LeArray[i] = (unsigned char)&array[i];
    //do more stuff to that array here before returning it
    return *LeArray;

}
int main()
{

    int i, ArraySize;
    unsigned char *before = NULL;
    unsigned short *after = NULL;
    ArraySize = 9;
    before = (unsigned char*) malloc(ArraySize*sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(i = 0; i<ArraySize; i++) before[i] = i+5; //to get some values in
    for (i = 0 ; i<ArraySize; i++) printf("\npre:%d\n",before[i]);
    after = foo( before, ArraySize ); 
    for (i = 0 ; i<ArraySize; i++) printf("\npost:%d\n",after[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

Any help tips hints or explanations would be of great help to me!! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function with all the strange places fixed to do what you expect it to do:

```
unsigned short* foo( unsigned char *array, int size) 
// notice the return type - it's a pointer
{
    int i;
    unsigned short *LeArray = NULL;
    LeArray = (unsigned short*) malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned short));
    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) LeArray[i] = (unsigned short)(array[i]);
    //do more stuff to that array here before returning it
    return LeArray; // notice NO DEREFERENCING here
}
```

Basically here are the issues you had:

- Return type of the function was not a pointer (was not an array)
- There was a strange pointer acrobatics you were doing (I would guess you were changing the code around until compiler stopped complaining)
- You dereferenced a pointer on return, essentially returning a value of the first element of the array (and not the whole array, as intended)

There's more to it, of course. namely:

- Looks like your "in" array is not changing - it's a *very* good practice to express that in the function's signature as `const unsigned char* array`
- You can further change the interface of your function to get an input argument for the resulting array

In that case you do the following:

```
void foo(const unsigned char *array, unsigned short* LeArray, int size) 
{
    int i;
    // no malloc as the LeArray is passed-in
    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) LeArray[i] = (unsigned short)(array[i]);
    //do more stuff to that array here before returning it
    return; // void return
}
```

Of course that assumes the array was pre-created in the calling function

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort :) I guess I don't understand that dereferencing operator too well, I'll learn that for the future

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

But you should return LeArray itself (which is the address in memory), and not *LeArray (which is the first element).

Answer (score 1):

`after = foo( before, ArraySize );` - Here you are calling the function `foo` and expecting a return value of type `unsigned short *`, but the function `foo` is returning `unsigned short` value. After that you are accessing the pointer to `unsigned short` variable `after` inside `main` function, which may leads to crash (an unexpected behaviour).

So change your function prototype as `unsigned short* foo( unsigned char *array, int size)` and do `return LeArray;`